# Can't go back from a nonroot page

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I've got a crash report from a user device; it's an `InvalidArgumentException` for a `NavigationService.GoBack` call. The exception message claims: "Cannot go back when CanGoBack is false". But the page class where this happened is not a top level page; it's only invoked from my main page (via a vanilla `NavigationService.Navigate` call). Why isn't the main page available in the navigation stack? Even if the page instance was unloaded for lack of memory, shouldn't the system quietly revive it in case of a navigation attempt?

Comment: I think the problem may be when the user for example rapidly taps back buton twice (or other button invoking navigation). The first navigation hadn't ended and the second can return CanGoBack false. Maybe some flag would solve the problem - set it when you start navigation, clear at the end.

Comment: Tried to reproduce with a deliberate double-tap, couldn't.

Comment: Thought I haven't seen your code - so I don't know if that would be possible, but I've managed to reproduce the issue - [here is my simple app](http://1drv.ms/1jVnq6y). When you navigate to second page, then button click is run asynchronously (to give a Chance for the user to tap it once more, I have implemented little delay). When I for example hit it three Times, I get your exception (on device). I know that it is only one possibility, but maybe will help.

Comment: I agree it's possible; but how long is the double-tap time window without an artificial delay? It's not Web navigation, it's all local.

Comment: I agree that it can be hard to get such an exception, especially if your bitton does nothing more than GoBack(). But since Navigation is asynchronous maybe user has other Apps in background running, or your App has other Tasks which slow Navigation (hard to say). And also user can have low memory, low cpu phone and is far more eager to find exceptions. Of course the problem may be somewhere else - it is my suspicion.